# Upside down water cup trick

Tags: home-experiment

I've been thinking about how this upside down water trick, you fill the cup with water to the brim and place a card on top then flip the water and card do not move.

how is this used in everyday life? work, home, etc

Comment: Read about Surface Tension.

Comment: Is the setup suspended in air with your hand and the cup being upside down? Are you sure this works, maybe a link to a video showing this or a GIF might help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Comment: @TechDroid  see this at around 2' 40" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXwSpcfYBD4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About an upside down cup of water against atmosphere pressure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73201/about-an-upside-down-cup-of-water-against-atmosphere-pressure)

Comment: It's really cool.

Answer (score 1):

What I believe is suspending the water from falling out of the cup is the pressure difference between the outside and the voided space above the water in the cup. What is fascinating is how air molecules aren'tt forcing their way in through the water into the partial vacuum. I believe it's due to the water being stable and the weight of the water pushing hard and creating a high surface tension on the surface of water across the cup brim. These are all based on logical and might not be true, but I can't think of something more scientific to prove that.

Comment: This looks like a fine answer to a completely different question.

Comment: I couldn't see any other reason why someone will want to suspend water in a cup except for water tricks. There may be, but I'll rather not talk than to say there isn't, so I thought maybe explaining the concept behind it to the OP might help him/her figure out something. If you know about some, you might be willing to share so I add it to the answer for completeness.