# what happens to the water in a space with no pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, water, liquid-state

[image]

as the boiling temreture of the water depends on the pressure of the space,
what happens to the water in a space with no pressure? does it boil cold? what about human blood?

Comment: Sort of related (not a duplicate): [Atmospheric pressure experiment using a cup with a fluid to hold a glass plate](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66658/140434)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the temperature of the container is kept constant.
If you add water liquid to a container in which the pressure is zero then depending on the volume of the container and the volume of the water some or all of the water liquid will become water vapour.
At the final equilibrium state if water liquid is still present then the pressure due to the water vapour will be the saturated vapour pressure of water at the temperature of the container.